# Cannot get wireless internet from wireless adapter

Tags: wireless, internet

I just set up my computer for dual boot windows 10/ubuntu 16.04 today.  After some struggle I have it working for the most part, but I cannot get wireless internet to work.  It is an Asus dual band wireless adapter.  It's working fine for windows 10, but not Ubuntu.

What I've tried:

I've tried out multiple solutions from this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers).

Typing

```
lspci -nn -d 14e4:
```

into the console hd no results, so I couldn't continue the first solution.

I followed the second solution, typing in the following into the console:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | egrep 'bcm'
cd /etc/modprobe.d/
sudo gedit blacklist.conf
```

and then I put a # before the approprite line, saved and rebooted.  Unfortunately,

```
rfkill list all
```

Returned nothing as well.  I'm not sure what to do at this point, any suggestions would be great.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you have a Broadcom card? The lspci (lack of) results suggests not.

Comment: I'm not sure! It was a suggestion from someone on reddit.  If you have a different suggestion I'm all ears, I'm not sure of the problem myself.

Comment: Is it internal or USB? If the latter it should show up with lsusb, not lspci. Please check and add the relevant information.

Comment: It's USB.  I'll try that now

Comment: Please run lsusb and post the only pertaining to the wifi only.

Comment: 0b05:17e5 ASUSTek Computer, Inc

Comment: 0b05:17e5 is not supported. The available drivers are for Windows only. It may or may not work with *ndiswrapper* and the .inf files from old Windows XP drivers (yes, really). @chili555 may be able to help you. PS - A support dongle that works out of the box may cost as little as $8. Consider that and the time it'll take to do all it's needed with the ndiswrapper hack and no guarantees... Easy answer for me but to each its own. Good luck.

Comment: That is... most unfortunate.  My computer is on the very opposite end of my apartment with  wall in between, so I was looking for something to ensure  decent connection.  Well, thanks for your help, if @chili555 is able to help walk me through it (I'm most definitely  novice), then I'm down to try but I might look into another dongle.